# Compile with multiple cores with Intel Fortran for Linux

Tags: build, compilation, parallel-processing, makefile, fortran

there,

I ran into trouble in compiling my Fortran program. It took me over 40 mins to build the program on my institute's computer. I used the following specification for compiling my current program with the Intel Fortran compiler for Linux. Would anyone be kindly letting me know how to modify my command so that the compilation is done with the full support of multiple cores (in my case 8 cores per CPU)?

Thanks,

Li

```
FC= mpiifort
FCFLAGS = -g -O3 -openmp -xSSE4.2 -axAVX -mt_mpi -I$(MKLROOT)/include/intel64/lp64 -I$(MKLROOT)/include       
LDFLAGS = $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_blas95_lp64.a \
      $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a \
      $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a \
      -Wl,--start-group \
      $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_cdft_core.a \
      $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a \
      $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a \
      $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a \
      -Wl,--end-group \
      $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a \
      -lpthread -lm

PROGRAM = main         
all: ${PROGRAM}
main: universe.o model.o variable.o toolbox.o
main.o: universe.o
universe.o: model.o
model.o: variable.o
variable.o: toolbox.o
%: %.o
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) 
%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $< $(LDFLAGS)
.PHONY: clean 
clean:
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" ! -name "_*.txt" -exec rm '{}' \;
    rm -f *.o
rm -f *.mod
rm -f *~
rm -f *.gz
```

Comment: what did you find in the documentation, how did you then try to apply it, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `make -j N`, where N is the number of parallel make jobs you want to run concurrently. In your case, with 8 cores, that would be 8 or thereabouts.

Note that the number of source files and the dependencies between them can also limit the number of jobs make is able to run concurrently. In your case it seems you have a linear dependency chain between your object files, allowing no concurrency, so you might want to split your code into more source files.